# Disk drive for /mnt/hogwarts is not ready yet or not present

Tags: mount, raid, raid5

**Note:** I'm a hardware and Ubuntu newbie so I may need hand holding.

**Problem:**
I have a RAID 5 that someone (I moved away so they aren't accessible) set up for me. I tried to turn on my server again after moving and now I get the error **Disk drive for /mnt/hogwarts is not ready yet or not present**.

I can see my drive (it's listed under devices as 4.0 TB Volume and there are files in there also when clicking on it the folder name is d5078b38-f7ec-427c-82bf-b2770227415d).

I can see the **hogwarts** directory listed under bookmarks (there's nothing in there). I looked in **/etc/fstab** and see this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=myStringBlahBlah / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=anotherLongStringHere none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md0   /mnt/hogwarts   ext4  defaults 0 0
```

My end goal is to be able to access the server like I used to from my mac. Both computers are connected to the same wireless router.

*UPDATE*

I tried `findmnt /dev/md0` but got nothing. If I just do `findmnt` by itself I get this.

```
TARGET   SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/dev/pts devpts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
```

Comment: What networking method did your mac use to connect to and login to the server? Did you set that up on your Ubuntu system, too? (/etc/fstab simply tells the system where to find disks, it doesn't login).

Comment: On your server, enter the command `findmnt /dev/md0`, copy the results and paste them into your question, please.

Comment: I didn't set anything up on my mac. I just connected to my linksys router and the server just showed up in my finder. Also I tried `findmnt /dev/md0` but got nothing.